# Monotouch Replacing the RootViewController

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

Using MonoTouch I add a LogonViewController to the Window and show it on FinishedLaunching:

```
        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        window.RootViewController = new LogonViewController();
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

In the **LogonViewController**, how do I add the main VC, called **MainViewContoller** and remove the **LogonViewController**? (This is the action that will happen once the user is logged in.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if it's possible to replace the `window.RootViewController`, that's not how it's usually done. Most of the time, you define your `RootViewController` and handle your navigation, including login, from there. That's at least how I do it.

```
//AppDelegate.cs
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    window.RootViewController = new MainViewController ();      
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
    return true;
}

//MainViewController.cs
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    if (not_logged_in)
        PresentViewController (new LoginViewController (), true, ()=>{});
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For what its worth this is how I've done it before.

```
public static void swapRootView(UIViewController newView, UIViewAnimationOptions opt)
        {
            UIView.Transition(mainWindow, 0.5, opt, delegate{
                mainWindow.RootViewController = newView;

            },null);
        }
```

Then after login is ok, call that method with this option.

```
swapRootView(yourNewViewController, UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight);
```